# How to Add Explode effect to JQplot Pie Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

I'm using "JqPlot" chart for plotting pie chart by using the "jqplot.pieRenderer.js"

library; what my requirement is whenever a pie slice is clicked it should explode

The present scenario : [jqplot example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php) click on any slice [it do not explode]

What i want : [highcharts example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend) [see how each pie explodes on click]

```
$('#chart').bind('jqplotDataClick', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    alert(plot.series[seriesIndex].seriesColors[pointIndex]);
});
```

now on click it shows color. but i want to explode it

Is it possible and if not please explain me the reason ? i'm stuck, 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/Gb7Lt/4/) is my fiddle for jqplot

Comment: ya here is the fiddle when pie clicked it shows color now i want to explode that part  http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/Gb7Lt/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here i edit my js file and make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/UmT5G/5/)

forget the my old answer 
i just manage one parameter and change radius and margin for specific pie .

```
function handleClick(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {

    if (neighbor) {
        var ins = [neighbor.seriesIndex, neighbor.pointIndex, neighbor.data];
        var evt = jQuery.Event('jqplotDataClick');
        evt.which = ev.which;
        evt.pageX = ev.pageX;
        evt.pageY = ev.pageY;
        plot.target.trigger(evt, ins);
        if($.jqplot.PieRenderer.prototype.selectedSlice == neighbor.pointIndex){
            unexpload(plot);
        }else{
            $.jqplot.PieRenderer.prototype.selectedSlice = neighbor.pointIndex;
            plot.replot();    
        }

    }else if (neighbor == null) {
        unexpload (plot);
    }
}

function unexpload(plot){
    $.jqplot.PieRenderer.prototype.selectedSlice = null;
    plot.destroy();
    plot.replot();
}
```

Comment: Could you please suggest what to do if we want legend with names and not percentage?. can you update jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

hey i am trying to solve same problem  not success yet but if u want to try yourself the start from here
editing 
"jqplot.pieRenderer.js" it has some logic to show highlight pie on mouse over and mouse leave  event 
i am follow same logic for my pie explode.
i modify the method in script 
this is like create one canvas to explode just like highlight canvas and 
bind the click method to hide show it.

```
function postPlotDraw() {
    // Memory Leaks patch    
    if (this.plugins.pieRenderer && this.plugins.pieRenderer.highlightCanvas) {
        this.plugins.pieRenderer.highlightCanvas.resetCanvas();
        this.plugins.pieRenderer.highlightCanvas = null;
    }

    if (this.plugins.pieRenderer && this.plugins.pieRenderer.exploadedCanvas) {
        this.plugins.pieRenderer.exploadedCanvas.resetCanvas();
        this.plugins.pieRenderer.exploadedCanvas = null;
    }

    this.plugins.pieRenderer = {highlightedSeriesIndex:null};
    this.plugins.pieRenderer = {exploadedSeriesIndex:null};

    this.plugins.pieRenderer.highlightCanvas = new $.jqplot.GenericCanvas();
    this.plugins.pieRenderer.exploadedCanvas = new $.jqplot.GenericCanvas();

    // do we have any data labels?  if so, put highlight canvas before those
    var labels = $(this.targetId+' .jqplot-data-label');
    if (labels.length) {
        $(labels[0]).before(this.plugins.pieRenderer.highlightCanvas.createElement(this._gridPadding, 'jqplot-pieRenderer-highlight-canvas', this._plotDimensions, this));
        $(labels[0]).before(this.plugins.pieRenderer.exploadedCanvas.createElement(this._gridPadding, 'jqplot-pieRenderer-exploaded-canvas', this._plotDimensions, this));
    }
    // else put highlight canvas before event canvas.
    else {
        this.eventCanvas._elem.before(this.plugins.pieRenderer.highlightCanvas.createElement(this._gridPadding, 'jqplot-pieRenderer-highlight-canvas', this._plotDimensions, this));
        this.eventCanvas._elem.before(this.plugins.pieRenderer.exploadedCanvas.createElement(this._gridPadding, 'jqplot-pieRenderer-exploaded-canvas', this._plotDimensions, this));
    }

    var hctx = this.plugins.pieRenderer.highlightCanvas.setContext();
    var ectx = this.plugins.pieRenderer.exploadedCanvas.setContext();

    this.eventCanvas._elem.bind('mouseleave', {plot:this}, function (ev) { unhighlight(ev.data.plot); });
}
```

here is my click function

```
function handleClick(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    unhighlight (plot);
    if (neighbor) {
        var ins = [neighbor.seriesIndex, neighbor.pointIndex, neighbor.data];
        var evt = jQuery.Event('jqplotDataClick');
        evt.which = ev.which;
        evt.pageX = ev.pageX;
        evt.pageY = ev.pageY;
        plot.target.trigger(evt, ins);
        var pidx = neighbor.pointIndex;
        var sidx = 0;
        var s = plot.series[sidx];
        var canvas = plot.plugins.pieRenderer.exploadedCanvas;
        canvas._ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas._ctx.canvas.width, canvas._ctx.canvas.height);
        s._highlightedPoint = pidx;
        plot.plugins.pieRenderer.exploadedSeriesIndex = sidx;
        s.renderer.drawSlice.call(s, canvas._ctx, s._sliceAngles[pidx][0], s._sliceAngles[pidx][1],plot.seriesColors[pidx], false,sidx);
    }
}
```

and also some changes in drawSlice()  method added one more parameter for exploded slice index and then use it in method for check and just add more margins and etc ..
this method have long code so i can't paste all code here so just pasting only changed data here

```
if(sidx != null && sidx == $.jqplot.PieRenderer.prototype.selectedSlice){
            rprime = calcRPrime(ang1, ang2,this.sliceMargin+10, this.fill, this.lineWidth);
        }
```

and in doDraw() function

```
if(sidx != null && sidx == $.jqplot.PieRenderer.prototype.selectedSlice){
            ctx.arc(0,0, rad+30, ang1, ang2, false);
            ctx.lineTo(0,0);
        }else{
            ctx.arc(0, 0, rad, ang1, ang2, false);
            ctx.lineTo(0,0);        
        }
```

also don't forget to put and

```
$.jqplot.PieRenderer.prototype.selectedSlice = null;
```

and in your html script

```
 $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {                
                $.jqplot.PieRenderer.prototype.selectedSlice = seriesIndex;
                }
        );
```

this is not the end..
i am still on it
if i get solution i will edit this thanks!!